# How to add a parameter via videojs contrib-hls to requests triggered by m3u8 manifest from the browser side

Tags: http-live-streaming, video.js

Is there a way to add a parameter to each request that was triggered by an m3u8 manifest, from the browser side in videojs contrib-hls?

For instance - via a customised loader (like [in this question](https://github.com/video-dev/hls.js/issues/2152#issuecomment-468861093)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

videojs-contrib-hls was succeeded by http-streaming, which is included in Video.js v7 by default. You can set a function to modify each request with [player.hls.xhr.beforeRequest](https://github.com/videojs/http-streaming/blob/master/README.md#hlsxhr).

This only works if http-streaming is playing HLS with Media Source Extensions, it's not possible to change requests with browsers' native playback. For some browsers with native HLS support, the [override native](https://github.com/videojs/http-streaming/blob/master/README.md#overridenative) option can be used to ensure http-streaming plays the video but this is notably not possible on iOS, which does not support MSE.

Comment: so what is solution which would work for all OS and all main browsers ? please help